# Control Panel Icon left after MSI Uninstallation

Tags: deployment

I built a MSI for unattended deployment which installes a application (usually installed with install shield which is not supported by the customers deployment software).

This MSI also installes a icon in the Control Panel.

After uninstallation everything is removed but the icon in the Control Panel.

The funny thing is: I neighter can't find a .cpl nor a registry key regarding to this icon.

Where I searched for the registry keys:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion \
  Explorer \ ControlPanel \ NameSpace
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion
  \ Explorer \ ControlPanel \ NameSpace

Comment: Any chance this was a 32-bit MSI on a 64-bit OS?

Comment: Yes it was but I searched the Software\Wow6432Node\ paths too...

Answer (score 0):

Check your Windows, System32 and SysWow64 folders for EXE files from that program.  Flash and Java are both known to do this and not have an entry in the Control Panel namespace.  Deleting the corresponding EXE gets rid of the icon.

Also, some CPLs are recorded here as well:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Control Panel\Cpls